# Animate bubblesort algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a simple animation of the bubblesort algorithm. I have a few divs with text inside: https://codepen.io/menezesr08/pen/pozYMKG

My goal is to swap the text inside the divs, as the algorithm is performing the swaps. My initial approach was to get all the divs, loop through them and change the 'innerHTML' when making a swap. This html change happens too quickly, so is there a way to slow this down so it appears to be animating?

```
<div class="box">
  <p>8</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>2</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>10</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>12</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout`, `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame` the latter being the recommended, but harder to master

Comment: This would be difficult to achieve using a loop, because it involves asynchronous tasks like waiting/animating.  Instead, try to make it work first with an extra button which when clicked will go to the next step.  Once you have this, remove the button and trigger it using `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using latest browsers, you can try something like below (self contained css and JS). Uses CSS transitions and promise with async/await syntax. You can run the code snippet directly here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=
    
    , initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .box1 {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background: red;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        transition: transform 1s linear;
      }

      p {
        text-align: center;
        color: yellow;
        font-size: 30px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class=" box1">
      <p>8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box1">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box1">
      <p>12</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box1">
      <p>10</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box1">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box1">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <script>
      var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

      var firstNumberHTML = divs[0].getElementsByTagName("p");
      var maxNumberDiv = divs[0];
      var maxNumber = Number(firstNumberHTML[0].innerHTML);
      async function bubbleSort (){
         for (var i = 1; i < divs.length; i++) {
         let currentNumberHTML = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("p");
         let number = Number(currentNumberHTML[0].innerHTML);
         await new Promise(res => {
             setTimeout(() => res("delay"), 1000);
         })
        if (maxNumber > number) {
            const offset = divs[i].getBoundingClientRect().x -
            maxNumberDiv.getBoundingClientRect().x;
            let prevTranslateMaxDiv = maxNumberDiv.style.transform.replace("translateX","").replace("(","").replace(")", "").replace("px", ""); 
            prevTranslateMaxDiv = Number(prevTranslateMaxDiv) === NaN ? 0: Number(prevTranslateMaxDiv);
            maxNumberDiv.style.transform = `translateX(${prevTranslateMaxDiv + offset}px)`;
            divs[i].style.transform = `translateX(-${offset}px)`;
          } else {
            maxNumberDiv = divs[i];
            maxNumber = number;
          }      
      }
      }
      bubbleSort();
     
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```